# Trying to implement a custom font on a website. Tried the follow code with no success

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to use VAGRoundedStd-Thin.otf as a font for my headings.
I've got the font and I placed it in my website folder using ftp.

After that i have put the following code in the css file.

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"VAG Rounded W02 Thin";
    src:url("rimowaedition.com/VAGRoundedStd-Thin.otf") format("opentype"); 
}

h2 {
    font-family: "VAG Rounded W02 Thin" !important;
}
```

I got frustrated and started putting important for the code but it didn't matter.
Any ideas on how i can get it to use the font.

Link to the website : http://rimowaedition.com/

Comment: Even if you succeed in adding your font, it most likely wont work on other browsers/OS without doing allot of extra work. Use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and upload your otf fonts and it will convert it to other formats for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: I think the problem is in the location of the font file.
are you getting any errors in the console.

Comment: Fontsquirrel wont work for me since its a paid font . They only do free fonts.

Comment: Somebody was asking a similar question a while ago. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202569/font-face-runs-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox-formats-of-fonts

Comment: Thank you sir, i will definitely go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this.

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"VAG Rounded W02 Thin";
    src:url("http://rimowaedition.com/VAGRoundedStd-Thin.otf") format("opentype"); 
}
```

Hopefully this works!

Comment: Hi , just wondering either i am blind or they look same to me . Don't want to sound rude . Its just all this is getting to my head i think.

Comment: I changed the location of the font. You just had `rimowaedition.com/VAGRoundedStd-Thin.otf` but you needed `http://` at the front so I changed it to `http://rimowaedition.com/VAGRoundedStd-Thin.otf`